# esc key close bootstrap modal but doesn't close select2 dropdown inside it

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

I implement select2 to my dropdown list,that located inside the bootstrap modal window.

```
<div class="modal-body">
...
<div class="controls">
    @Html.DropDownList("Experts", new SelectList(Model.ExpertsInfo, "UserId", "FullName"),
      string.Empty, new { @class = "select", id = "expert-select", autocomplete = "true", autofocus = "", style = "width: 295px;" }                       
                </div>
...
    </div>

 $("#experts").select2({
            allowClear: true,
            minimumResultsForSearch: -1,
            formatNoMatches: function () {
                return "@CommonResources.NoMatches";
            }
        });
```

All working good but if i closing modal window,when dropdown is open,modal window hiding but dropdown remains!Where did i make mistake?And Will i have to implement my own handler for esc key?

Comment: create a fiddle with your code ... could be more self explanatory...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Select2 API**

In order to close the select2 you use the following:

```
 $('#experts').select2("close");
```

You would then tap into the close event depending on the version of bootstrap:

**Bootstrap 3**

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#experts').select2("close");
})
```

**Bootstrap 2**

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden', function () {
   $('#experts').select2("close");
})
```

**Final solution**

As per Anton's comments:

```
$('#expert-modal').keyup(function (e) { if (e.keyCode == 27) {
       $('#s2id_experts').select2("close"); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: unfortunately,bootstrap 2.3 =(

Comment: @AntonKozlovsky I also noticed that the close for the select has changed to `$('#experts').select2("close");` I updated that too. :)

Comment: final version (because your decision close modal first,than dropdown,and my decision close dropdown first) But thanks a lot!) `$('#expert-modal').keyup(function (e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 27) {
                    $('#s2id_experts').select2("close");
                }
            });`

Comment: @AntonKozlovsky Nice one, will add to answer. Good luck with the rest.